# Some modifications for multicolumn and multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I'm using this code for creating a table in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{c c | c c | c c c | c c c c}

  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  && \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{PV}} & \\
   &  & F & N &  & F & N &  & F & N & \\
  \noalign{\hrule height 0.7pt}
  \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{AV}}}} & F & 8 & 9 &  & 11 & 12 &  & 150 & A & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\scriptsize ABC}}}\\
  & NF & 14 & 15 &  & 17 & 18 &  & A & A & \\

\noalign{\hrule height 0.7pt}
    \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{AV}}}} & F & 8 & 9 &  & 11 & 12 &  & 15X & A & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{{\scriptsize dddd}}}}\\
  & NF & 14 & 15 &  & 17 & 18 &  & A & A & \\

  \noalign{\hrule height 0.7pt}
  && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{MSP}} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{DBE}} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{VDE}} \\
\end{tabular}


\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I need some modification in `multicolumn` and `multirow`. I want remove red boxes (line in red boxes) from output, convert black vertical lines to red lines (in middle) and have two black boxes in right(black boxes around ABC and dddd). How can I do this modification using `multicolumn` and `multirow`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{c c | c c | c c | c c| c|}


 \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{PV}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & F & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{N} &   F &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{N} &  F & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{N} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
\hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{AV}}} & F & 8 & 9 &  11 & 12 &  150 & A & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\scriptsize ABC}}}\\
  & NF & 14 & 15 &  17 & 18 &  A & A & \\

\hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{AV}}} & F & 8 & 9 &  11 & 12 &  15X & A & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{{\scriptsize dddd}}}}\\
  & NF & 14 & 15 &  17 & 18 &  A & A & \\
\hline
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{MSP}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{DBE}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{VDE}} \\
\end{tabular}


\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution based on your initial code, with coloured vertical lines as requested. I added the `caption` for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table. I had to use `\hhline` for technical reasons:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell, hhline}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.7pt}
\caption{MM}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{c c | c c !{\color{red}\vrule width0.7pt}c c !{\color{red}\vrule width0.7pt} c c c}
 \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{PV}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}& F & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & F & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & F & N & \\
\hhline{~-------~}
 \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{AV}}}} & F & \cellcolor{gray!12}{8} & 9 & \cellcolor{gray!12}{11} & 12 & \cellcolor{gray!12}{150} & A & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\scriptsize ABC}}}\\
 & NF & 14 & \cellcolor{gray!12}{15} & 17 & \cellcolor{gray!12}{18} & A & \cellcolor{gray!12}{A} & \\
\hhline{~-------~}
 \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{AV}}}} & F & \cellcolor{gray!12}{8} & 9 & \cellcolor{gray!12}{11} & 12 & \cellcolor{gray!12}{15X} & A & \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{{\scriptsize dddd}}}}\\
 & NF & 14 & \cellcolor{gray!12}{15} & 17 & \cellcolor{gray!12}{18} & A & \cellcolor{gray!12}{A} & \\
 \cline{2-8}
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{MSP}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{DBE}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{VDE}} \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[\textdagger]BBBddddd
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]